# How to hook IE console output when hosting webbrowser control

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, console, webbrowser-control, hosting

I have an application that hosts the IE WebBrowser control and want to add the ability to intercept and display any output to the IE debug console window in my own window (or log file or ....).

I haven't found any information on where this interface is defined or how I can hook into it, something like the browser IOleCommandTarget::Exec events.